# Split range into uniform intervals

Tags: c++, x86, floating-point, precision

I want to split a range with `double` borders into `N>=2` equal or near equal intervals.

I found a suitable function in [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/ftp/pub/speech/software/praatlib-0.3/src/GSL/gsl_histogram__init.c):

```
make_uniform (double range[], size_t n, double xmin, double xmax)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
      double f1 = ((double) (n-i) / (double) n);
      double f2 = ((double) i / (double) n);
      range[i] = f1 * xmin +  f2 * xmax;
    }
}
```

However, when
`xmin = 241141` (binary `0x410D6FA800000000`)
`xmax = 241141.0000000001` (binary `0x410D6FA800000003`)
`N = 3`
the function produces

```
[0x410D6FA800000000,
 0x410D6FA800000000,
 0x410D6FA800000002,
 0x410D6FA800000003]
```

instead of desired

```
[0x410D6FA800000000,
 0x410D6FA800000001,
 0x410D6FA800000002,
 0x410D6FA800000003]
```

How achieve uniformity without resorting to long arithmetics (i already have a long arithmetics solution but it is ugly and slow)? Bit twiddling and x86 (x86-64, so no extended precision) assembler routines are acceptable.

UPDATE:

General solution is needed, without premise that `xmin`, `xmax` have equal exponent and sign:

- `xmin` and `xmax` may be of any value except infinity and NaN (possibly also excluding denormalized values for sake of simplicity).
- `xmin < xmax`
- `(1<<11)-1>=N>=2`
- i'm ready for major (in 2-3 orders) performance loss

Comment: Maybe reorder the operation might have better precision in your case: (`xmin + i * (xmax - xmin) / n`).

Comment: @Jarod42 you cannot do `xmax - xmin` as it can produce infinite value.

Comment: I would say that you won't have simple formula with correct precision for all possible input parameters, you have to do some trade of.

Comment: With what normal values does `xmax - xmin` produce infinity?

Comment: @Nelfeal: `DBL_MAX - (-DBL_MAX)` would overflow to +Inf.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright I admit I wasn't thinking about negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x87 still exists in x86-64, and 64-bit kernels for mainstream OSes do correctly save/restore the x87 state for 64-bit processes.  Despite what you may have read, x87 is fully usable in 64-bit code.

Outside of Windows (i.e. the x86-64 System V ABI used everywhere else), `long double` is the 80-bit native x87 native format.  This will probably solve your precision problem for x86 / x86-64 only, if you don't care about portability to ARM / PowerPC / whatever else that only has 64-bit precision in HW.

Probably best to only use `long double` for temporaries inside the function.

I'm not sure what you have to do on Windows to get a compiler to emit 80-bit extended FP math.  It's certainly possible in asm, and supported by the kernel, but the toolchain and ABI make it inconvenient to use.

---

x87 is only somewhat slower than scalar SSE math on current CPUs.  80-bit load/store is extra slow, though, like 4 uops on Skylake instead of 1 (https://agner.org/optimize/) and a few cycles extra latency for `fld m80`.

For your loop having to convert int to FP by storing and using x87 `fild`, it might be something like at most a factor of 2 slower than what a good compiler could do with SSE2 for 64-bit double.

And of course `long double` will prevent auto-vectorization.

Comment: I did write a routine for `x87` and it worked good but that PR was rejected by my superior on the grounds that there are no other places in the code base where `x87` is used. The final solution was to use that GNU routine from the header and to accept loss of precision when it is relatively small to the interval length. For very short intervals we treat mantissae as integers and perform a costly but precise algorithm which includes integer divisions.

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev: That's presumably portable to non-x86.  In GNU C you can use `__float128` to get double-double extended precision.  Or with an `#ifdef __x86_64__` you can use `__float80` if that's accurate enough, without having to hand-write any x87 asm.

Answer (score 0):

I see two choices: reordering the operations as `xmin + (i * (xmax - xmin)) / n`, or dealing directly with the binary representations. Here is a example for both.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double xmin = 241141;
    double xmax = 241141.0000000001;
    size_t n = 3, i;
    double range[4];

    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << std::fixed;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        range[i] = xmin + (i * (xmax - xmin)) / n;

        std::cout << range[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto uxmin = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long&>(xmin);
    auto uxmax = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long&>(xmax);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        auto rangei = ((n-i) * uxmin + i * uxmax) / n;
        range[i] = reinterpret_cast<double&>(rangei);

        std::cout << range[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59c37df89c17daa0)

Comment: Not sure `reinterpret_cast` is valid. even more how mantissa is handled in general case.

Comment: @Jarod42 It certainly isn't in the general case. But it does work with IEEE 754 `double`, and if `unsigned long long` is the same length as `double`, and if the range contains no change in exponent or sign. Of course dealing directly with binary representations or floating-point numbers is dangerous. But more importantly, expecting perfect results from operations on floating-point numbers is optimistic (perfect in the sense of "precise", not "well-defined"). You often have to think carefully about the order of these operations.

Comment: Reference type punning violates strict aliasing, doesn't it?  The same as pointer casting like `uint64_t uxmin = *(uint64_t*)&xmin` would.  Type-punning with memcpy would be fine, assuming IEEE754 and FP endian = integer endian like on x86.

Comment: I think you're assuming that xmin and xmax have the same exponent; the next representable `double` bit-pattern is an integer increment/decrement away, but they're not uniformly distributed.  Also, FP uses sign/magnitude while integer uses 2's complement, so I'm not sure this works correctly across 0.